# Nvidia driver won't load - Ubuntu Win10 Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

**Problem / Symptoms:**

I have Win10 / Ubuntu 18.10 dual boot on my Asus GL703GS laptop which has worked great for months. However, after connecting / disconnecting HDMI cord while in Win10, Ubuntu can apparently no longer use the graphics card.

- It lists the display as "Unknown Display"
- Resolution is set to 800x480 and no option to change it.
- On Win10 the GPU works and it had worked on Ubuntu for months prior so I don't think it's the hardware.
- I suspect Windows has locked up some display driver resource that persists after reboot.

**Already tried:**

- Cannot reinstall Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu, says "nvidia-uvm" is already loaded and it cannot be unloaded. Tried reinstalling through the Nvidia .run file, Ubuntu automatic driver update, etc, no luck.
- Tried uninstalling Nvidia drivers and removing all traces of it in Win10 and reinstalling it. No point in this process changed anything for Ubuntu, same issues there.
- Tried many tutorials / answers related to xrandr but none of them work at all.
- No results from any lsof nvidia commands.

**Machine Details:**

- Output of `lspci | grep NVIDIA`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (rev a1)`

- Output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

`...
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin`

- Output of `lsmod | grep -i nvidia`

`nvidia_uvm            786432  0
nvidia_drm             40960  0
nvidia_modeset       1040384  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              16621568  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   458752  3 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia`